# How to login to website with form (method=post)?

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, msxml

I have written code to scrape HTML of a website that requires login. Originally I used IE automation but it was slow so I'm exploring other option including MSXML2.XMLHTTP.

I can login to website without any issues with IE but can't make it work with MSXML2.XMLHTTP.

This works:

```
With ieDoc.Forms(0)
    .textLogin.Value = GPROUsername
    .textPassword.Value = GPROPassword
    .submit
End With
```

Unable to login with:

```
Sub TestHTTPLogin()
Dim XMLHttpRequest As Object

LoginForm.Show

Set XMLHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With XMLHttpRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://gpro.net/gb/Login.asp?langCode=gb&Redirect=gpro.asp", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "content=text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        .send "textLogin=" & GPROUsername & "&" _
          & "textPassword=" & GPROPassword
    
        Debug.Print .responseText
   
    End With

    Set XMLHttpRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is the HTML of the target website

```
<form method="post" action="Login.asp?langCode=gb&Redirect=gpro.asp" style="margin:0px" ID="Form1">
        
        <tr>
            <td>Username or Email address:</td>
            <td class="leftalign"><input type="text" name="textLogin" autofocus value="" class="pad" style="font-size:16px;padding:4px !Important;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #348bf8;margin-top:3px;width:180px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="textPassword" ID="Password1" class="pad" style="font-size:16px;padding:4px !Important;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #348bf8;margin-top:3px;width:180px"> <a href="LostPassword.asp" class="password"> Lost password?</a></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="" ID="token">
                <input type="hidden" name="Logon" value="Login">
                <input type="submit" name="LogonFake" value="Sign in" class="halo micro">
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        </table>
</form>
```

I decided to use WinHTTPRequest instead. Code below works.

```
LoginForm1 = "textLogin=" & GPROUsername & "&" & "textPassword=" & GPROPassword & "&" & "Logon=Login"
 
Set HttpRequest = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
Set Managerhtml = New HTMLDocument
With HttpRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://gpro.net/gb/Login.asp?langCode=gb&Redirect=gpro.asp", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "GO"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "Host", "gpro.net"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(LoginForm1)
        .send LoginForm1
        .send "JSON=textLogin"
End With
```

Comment: Manually login using browser and use developer network tab to see what is actually going on with POST request and mimic that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems the browser sends a token value but I have no idea how it's generated.

Comment: Is there an API available with documentation? Is there an OAUTH process or some such?

Comment: @QHarr I don't know what's token is but when I omit it the code works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Public Declare Function InternetSetOptionStr Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetSetOptionA" (ByVal hInternet As Long, ByVal lOption As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lBufferLength As Long) As Integer

Private Sub ClearCacheHistory()
    InternetSetOptionStr 0, 42, 0, 0
End Sub

Sub GPRO_Login()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, sUser As String, sPass As String
    ClearCacheHistory
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    sUser = "youremail": sPass = "yourpass"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://gpro.net/gb/Login.asp?langCode=gb&langCode=gb&Redirect=gpro.asp", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "textLogin=" & sUser & "&textPassword=" & sPass & "&Logon=Login"
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        If html.querySelector("ul[id='nav'] li a[href*='/gb/Login']").innerText = "Logout" Then
            MsgBox "Login Success", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Login Failure", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have managed to find the solution. Sending "json=login" after the form triggers the login script.