# Excel VBA XML HTTP Request to Scrape Table on Page with Login

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I had code set up and working fine until the past couple of days.  It is an Excel VBA XML HTTP Request to scrape a table on a web page that is behind a paywall login that I subscribe to.

Thing is - the code ran perfectly for several weeks.  I learned there are some rules with the website where it limits the number of logins across multiple devices/browsers (i.e. - if I manually sign-in on Internet Explorer, it'll prompt me to log in again on Chrome if I refresh the page there).  I'm bummed because it was working so well without an explicit need to write in some sort of log in code.

Here is what I've been working with:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub ETR_150_XMLHTTP()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.establishtherun.com/evan-silvas-top-150-2020/", False
    XMLPage.send

    If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
      MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
      Exit Sub
    End If

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

    End Sub



    Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

        Sheets("XMLHTTP").Select
    
        RowNum = 1
        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
            ColNum = 1
            For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
                Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Next HTMLCell
        
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        Next HTMLRow
    
    Next HTMLTable

    End Sub
```

Is there a simple, easy way for me to tell the code to log in (if needed) to be able to access the page/table for scraping?

I'm still relatively new to VBA and, especially, web scraping - so any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465470/)

Comment: I'm so new at this that I don't know what I'm look at/for with that link.

Comment: I thought you are looking for a way of how to login using XMLHTTP ..

Comment: I am, I just don't know where to look in that thread and how to apply it to the code I have (that was working without having to declare login items).